# How to changes the photo width and height in React Native Vision Camera or chop it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I am simply trying to get a square image and lower the size of the image as much a possible while keep image text clear.

This is my attempt but it does not work.

```
const capturePhoto = async () => {
    const options = {
      qualityPrioritization: 'speed',
      skipMetadata: true,
      flash: 'off',
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
    };

    if (camera.current !== null) {
      const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto(options);
      const {height, width, path} = photo;
      console.log(
        `The photo has a height of ${height} and a width of ${width}.`,
      );
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 options (or a combo of them):

check the `format` options and find the aspect ration & quality you want: [Formats documentation](https://www.react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/formats) or use something like [expo-image-maniulator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/#actionrotate) to resize.
Cropping is another thing altogether.

Comment: how do you lock aspect ratio? for example you only want the camera to have 16:9 aspect ratio and get the result of 16:9 aspect ratio?

Comment: You’ll need to filter the devices with the “format” option. Docs: https://react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/formats

Answer (score 0):

you have to use format for it and have to add format prop in camera component

just like this.

```
const screenAspectRatio = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;

const format = useCameraFormat(device, [
    { fps: targetFps },
    { videoAspectRatio: screenAspectRatio },
    { videoStabilizationMode: 'auto' },
    { iso: 'max' },
    { videoHdr: true },
    { videoResolution: 'max' },
    { photoAspectRatio: screenAspectRatio },
    { photoResolution: 'max' },
    { pixelFormat: 'native' },
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).